# Jquery feedback dialog

Tags: jquery, feedback

I am trying to implement a feedback box for my site. I used jquery for this (http://grasshopperpebbles.com/demos/index.php/jqueryui/feedback/dialog). The explanation is given in the link Blog post. I am able to display the dialog box but the send_mail.php is not read. Why is that so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never mind. I fixed it myself. This is for those who are looking for the answer.

In the 'ui.imFeedBack-0.5.2.js' file I changed the sendFeedback function part. Here is the code - 

sendFeedBack: function() {
x=$("#imFeedBack-FormContainer").serialize();
$.post("send_mail.php",'&'+x,function(result){
$('#imFeedBack-FormContainer').html(result);
});
}
You could make changes to this according to your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I fixed it myself. This is for those who are looking for the answer. In the 'ui.imFeedBack-0.5.2.js' file I changed the sendFeedback function part. Here is the code -

```
sendFeedBack: function() { 
x=$("#imFeedBack-FormContainer").serialize();
$.post("send_mail.php",'&'+x,function(result){ 
           $('#imFeedBack-FormContainer').html(result); 
});
```

}

You could make changes to this according to your requirement